# Is it possible to use HTTP for Bing Ads Report API?

Tags: http, bing-ads-api

I would like to interact with the Bing Ads Report API using HTTP call but I can't find the endpoints to do so. LinkedIn which is also a Microsoft product offers that possibility, so I would think it's possible with Bing Ads to.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for Bing Ads Report API via HTTP endpoint.

Here's an article to read of why HTTPS over HTTP: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/why-use-https/.